# Register and use User's email domain

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, email

In my current application i want to add a new feature that customers will be able to register their own email domain server if they have any. Currently i am sending all emails using my own application domain.

I want to know how we can accomplish that using **ASP.NET WebApi & C#** that user will allow to validate and register their own email domains instead of using the default one.

Do we need user's **DKIM** and **SPF** records ?

Comment: _"I want to know how we can accomplish that"_ accomplish what? It's very unclear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: i have updated the question. Hope that make sense now

Comment: are you asking "how do i save a string containing email domain?"   or what?

Comment: i am asking how do we validate private domains. Like some of our customers wants to use their own email domains not that we are providing

Comment: I've no clue what you mean by "register". Where will the user register a domain?

Comment: Do you have your answer @RaviMittal? If not, can you give us an update to tell us what you expect?

Comment: no i don't have the answer yet. What we want that our customers can register their own email domain instead of using our default email service.

Answer (score 0):

### If the user provides the credentials to their own email service

Then you don't need to look at DKIM and SPF records. The user should do that himself.

You will have to collect from the user:

- email service type (smtp, mandrill, postmarkapp...)
- email service host name (if smtp)
- credentials or api key
- and maybe service-specific options

### If you use your own service to send emails

Then the user will have to add a DKIM entry and update the SPF entry on their domain name. You will have to provide the values to your user depending on your email service.

You can take inspiration from all those services that allow the same kind of feature ([mailchimp](http://kb.mailchimp.com/delivery/deliverability-research/set-up-custom-dkim), [mandrill](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582267-About-SPF-and-DKIM), [postmarkapp](http://support.postmarkapp.com/category/45-category), [zoho](https://www.zoho.com/campaigns/help/setup-spf-dkim.html)...).

### Check for DNS email records

In both cases, you can use a [DNS client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ARSoft.Tools.Net) to verify the DNS records are OK. You will be able to tell the user whether records are missing.

Here a sample code to start checking the SPF record with [ARSoft.Tools.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ARSoft.Tools.Net).

```
var client = new DnsClient(servers, 10000);
var spfRecords = client.Resolve(item.Name, RecordType.Txt);
if (result.AnswerRecords == null || result.AnswerRecords.Count == 0 || result.ReturnCode == ReturnCode.NxDomain)
{
    // spf record is missing
}
else if (result.AnswerRecords.Count == 1)
{
    // check the record value with SpfRecord.TryParse(item.ActualValue, out spf)
}
else
{
    // too many spf records
}
```